# OpenCL pass matrix as argument

Tags: matrix, opencl, send

How can I pass a List of Lists of ints to OpenCl?

I know how to sent an array of type int[], but I can't find a workaround to somehow send the above structure.

I could transform my List of Lists in an int[][], can that be send?

Comment: You can use Shared Virtual Memory if available on you platform. This way you wouldn't have to change the structure, and pointers would work just fine.

Answer (score 2):

Transform your 2D list into a 1D.

For example for a list [[0,1], [2,3]] change it to a [0,1,2,3]. And accessing elements list[y][x] becomes list[x + y*a] where a is number of columns.